# Join - order by vote-sum and check if user has voted

Tags: performance, sql, mysql, join

I have a vote and a comment table. Now I want to display all comments and order them by votes-sum. Sum because some votes can have a higher value than others.

Therefore I want to display if the user has voted already on a comment. So I need to get that value too.

This is my actual query:

```
SELECT *, SUM(v.`value`) as votesum, 

(
     SELECT 1 
     FROM votes 
     WHERE user_id = 123 and id = v.id

) as user_voted_already 

FROM comments as c
LEFT JOIN votes as v
ON c.id = v.`foreign_id` and v.`foreign_type` = 'comment'
WHERE c.`network_id` = 3183
GROUP BY ( v.`foreign_id`)
ORDER BY votesum DESC
```

It's working but I'm just wondering if this is the right way (or: the fastest way).

These are the table definitions:

```
votes (polymorphic):
    id
    user_id
    guest_ip (for guest votes)
    foreign_id
    foreign_type
    category
    value
    comment
    created_at
    updated_at

comments
    id
    network_id
    network_name
```

… and many others that I don't think are needed for the question.

Answer (score 1):

### Schema

Your schema isn't well normalized: you shouldn't have `network_name` in the `comments` table when you already have `network_id`.

### Non-standard `GROUP BY`

Standard SQL requires that when the query has a `GROUP BY`, all columns being selected must either be mentioned in the `GROUP BY` clause or be an aggregate function.  However, MySQL is sloppy, and allows non-sensical queries like yours that violate that rule, unless you enable the standard behaviour explicitly by setting the [`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) option on the server.  (When you write `SELECT *, …`, which `created_at` timestamp would you expect to appear in the results, for example?)

You wrote `` GROUP BY ( v.`foreign_id`) ``, but `GROUP BY c.id` would make it more obvious that you want to group by comment.

### Subselect

Subselects within the `SELECT` column list are a bit nasty, and can nearly always be expressed better.  In this case, I think that a `COUNT()` of votes whose `user_id` is 123 would do the job — and it doesn't require another join.

### Indentation

More meaningful indentation would make the query easier to read.  You don't have to indent it the way I suggest, but you should do something better than nearly no indentation at all.

### Suggested solution

```
SELECT c.id AS comment_id
     , SUM(v.value) AS votesum
     , COUNT(WHEN v.user_id = 123 THEN 1 END) > 0 AS user_voted_already
    FROM comments as c
        LEFT JOIN votes as v
            ON v.foreign_type = 'comment'
            AND v.foreign_id = c.id
    WHERE c.network_id = 3183
    GROUP BY c.id
    ORDER BY votesum DESC;
```